# Passing secure string to Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I need to pass a secure string as a parameter to Invoke-AzVMRunCommand. My code is

```
$pass=Read-Host "Enter Password for sysadmin" -AsSecureString
$stdstring  = ConvertFrom-SecureString $pass 

 $runcmdparameters=@{
      "sysadmincredential"=$stdstring           
                       }
        Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ServerResourceGroupName -VMName $VMVame -ScriptPath $TemplateFile  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -Parameter $runcmdparameters -Verbose
```

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand script

```
Param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$sysadmincredential
)

$cr=ConvertTo-SecureString $sysadmincredential

Out-File "C:\Temp\log.txt" -InputObject $cr -Append
```

However, the script fails with

> ConvertTo-SecureString : The system cannot find the path specified.
>   At
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.0\Downloads\s
>   cript11.ps1:4 char:5
>   + $cr=ConvertTo-SecureString $sysadmincredential
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], C    ryptographicException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_Cryptographic
>   Error,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

Thanks

Comment: this kinda makes no sense, why do you prompt for a secure string, but on the next line convert it back? just dont prompt for a secure string? also, try simplifying your script? just do `$sysadmincredential | Out-File c:\temp\log.txt` and see if that works

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: This is a bad practice to convert a secure string to a plain text and furthermore to pass it to another machine on the network. Two security holes in one small script. 
It will be better to put that password into a keyvault as a secret and then obtain it from the client VM to be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, you need to pass `-AsPlainText -Force`, the command should be `$cr = ConvertTo-SecureString $sysadmincredential -AsPlainText -Force`, then it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Due to priority change I am holding this work. I will let you know once I am back on it.